# Is there a unified wrapper for python's archive compresson packages?

Tags: python, file-compression

Python supports a lot of archive formats. I personally know of [tar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) (which supports [gzip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) and [bz2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html)), [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html), [rar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/), [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html), [lzma](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylzma) and 7z.

I find it a bit tedious and error-prone to do auto-detection of these formats by hand, than select the right package and deal with its respective API which is always slightly different from the others'.

Is there a unified API package that works with all these formats? It should need a minimum of additional packages to be installed and should be able to read archived file from the stream (without the need for real temporary files). I've seen [pyunpack](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyunpack). The problem I see with it is that it only unpacks and relies on external, non-Python tools. Is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Not *quite* the answer you are looking for but worth mentioning I think.

The python [File System library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fs) can open a number of different file systems with a unified interface and includes an [Opener](http://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/opener.html), `fs.opener()`, which takes a URI like specifier. This should open the file system appropriately if it is any of the supported types.  Current file system types include, *with some platform dependency*:

- MemoryFS
- OS
- RPCFS
- FTP
- SFTP
- S3
- Zip

This library is extensible for other file systems e.g.: there a couple of Dropbox integrations, [dropboxfs](https://github.com/btimby/fs-dropbox) & [fs-dropbox](https://github.com/btimby/fs-dropbox) available, and others so it might be worth looking at seeing if anybody else is interested in extending this to add the missing ones once and for all.